# “xxd -p” alternative for HP-UX - how to get the same results with “xd”?

Tags: hp-ux, xxd

I have a command which is very handy at work. It searches for a certain **STRING** inside some hex raw files with **FILENAME**. The command which I always used in Linux systems is:

```
  find . -name '**FILENAME**' | while read filename; do 
    xxd -p $filename | tr -d '\n' | grep -i "**STRING**" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then 
        echo "STRING FOUND IN $filename"; 
    fi; 
done
```

I did not build this command. On HP-UX systems, as xxd is not present, I would need to use xd. But I do not know how to get the same results as with xxd -p.

How could I adapt this command to run on HP-UX systems?

Comment: Can you install `vim`? `xxd` is part of that.

Comment: No.. I run this command on customer networks, and this specific one is HP-UX with no `vim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on HP-UX, so this has only been checked against [xd(1)](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/xd.1.html):

```
xd -b -An -v $filename
```

- `-An` prevents the offset from being shown
- `-b` defaults to single bytes, (octal for `od`, hex for `xd`)
- `-v` prevents identical lines from being replaced with `*`

(A lot of systems, mine included, have `od` but not `xd`.  So for portability, I use `od -tx1 -An -v $filename` instead.)

That will output individual hex bytes, with a space between each.  Changing the `tr` command to `tr -d [:space:]` will remove all whitespace, not just newlines.

Joining that all together, you need to replace the `xxd` and `tr` parts of your script so that the line looks like this:

```
xd -b -An -v $filename | tr -d '[:space:]' | grep -i "**STRING**" > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks @JigglyNaga! I am a very basic HP-UX user, so could you assist me in rewriting my first script with your alternative? The only variables in my original command are the **STRING** and the **FILENAME**.

Comment: Also, I checked and this system also has `od`.

Comment: @EXHALEXHALE Edited to show the exact line you need to include.

Comment: thanks! Worked without any hiccups. Now I can use this in HP-UX systems, which saves me much more time than you can imagine!

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
xxd -p < file | tr -d '\n'
```

could be replaced with a simple perl script

```
perl -ne 'foreach $c (split(//,$_)) { printf "%02x",ord($c)}' < file
```

Comment: Cheers! Could you help in rewriting my first command to have your alternative?

Comment: Quite literally in your original you had `xxd | tr`; replace those bits with the `perl` code and it _should_ just work.

Comment: I did not get to check this, as the above worked for me. But many thanks for your help Stephen! Cheers and have a nice weekend.